# ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND styles.css

Tags: nestjs, nodemailer

I m trying to send confirmation email to user but when applying CSS to handlebars.js files it seems to crash , further on if I remove the styles.css file from handlebars it is working perfectly fine

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND styles.css
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
```

Nodemailer transport

```
 transport: {
          host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
          port: 465,
          secure: true,
          auth: {
            user: config.get('MAIL_USER'),
            pass: config.get('MAIL_PASS'),
          },
        },
        template: {
          dir: join(__dirname, 'templates'),
          adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
          options: {
            strict: true,
          },
        },
```

Verification Template

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Email Verification</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./styles.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
      <h2>Verify your email address</h2>
      <p>Thank you for signing up with us. To complete the registration process,
        please click the button below to verify your email address:</p>
      <div class='btn-container'>
        <a href='{{url}}' class='btn'>Verify Email</a>
      </div>
      <p>If you didn't create an account, please ignore this email.</p>
      <p>Thank you,<br />The Localhost Team</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Nest-CLI

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "assets": ["**/*.hbs", "**/*.css"]
  },
  "watchAssets": true
}
```

I already tried different port with secure and other settings nothing seems to be working
and only creates issue when css is added , tried giving it the absolute path but no progress.